# manually set gateway using static routing

Tags: linux, networking, routes

For study purpose I want to setup the following networking

```
A: 
   10.130.247.92/16(private on eth1)
   128.199.227.240(public on eth0)
B: 
   10.130.237.218/16(private on eth1)
   128.199.211.182/18(public on eth0)
```

And use B as gateway for private route.
in A

```
root@privte2:~# ip route list
default via 128.199.192.1 dev eth0 
10.130.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link 
128.199.192.0/18 dev eth0  scope link
```

and

```
root@privte2:~# ip route add 10.130.0.0/16 via 10.130.247.92 dev eth1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Can anyone tell me where i did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this before. See if this can help you. First enable the ipforwarding in both the machines.

locate the line containing net.ipv4.ip_forward in the /etc/syscl.conf file and make the following change.
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

May be you need to restart for this.

Not really sure, Try this route command and see if it works.

Machine>$ route add -net 10.130.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 128.199.211.182

For instance see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/).